# Reduce size of Bootstrap date and time picker right spaces between spinner and date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, space, picker

I want to reduce the size of the space between spinner and date/time itself. I am using Bootstrap 3/4. Reason is I want to cram more fields on the screen for data entry.

Best if I show with a picture:

[image: Reduce the space circled]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: <div class="row" class ="full-width-div"> 
 <div class = "full-width-div">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
   <td>
    <input  data-mini="true"   type="date" value="2017-01-31"  name="invdate" id="invdate" "> 
   </td>

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the width as you want in the css file

```css
#invdate {
  width: 13rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" class="full-width-div">
    <div class="full-width-div">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input data-mini="true" type="date" value="2017-01-31" name="invdate" id="invdate">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
```

Else you can try bootstrap datepicker

```js
 $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});
```

```css
#filterDate2 {
   width:15rem;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="filterDate2">
          
          <!-- Datepicker as text field -->         
          <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="input-dates" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-addon" >
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```